# Configuring elasticsearch in JHipster project using prod yml

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, jhipster

I have an application built using the Jhipter generator, which is based on Spring Boot. The latest version of Jhipster allows you to include Elasticsearch as an option, so I have an application which runs an embedded instance of Elasticsearch in development mode and connects to a server instance in production mode.

When the application is running in development mode it connects perfectly fine to the embedded instance, but if I try to connect to an external instance I get the following error on console:

**ERROR 7804 --- [  restartedMain] .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]**

My application is using **Spring boot version 1.4.0.RELEASE** and according to the elasticsearch.yml, the application has **elasticsearch 2.3.5**

My application-prod.yml settings:

```
spring:
    data:
        elasticsearch:
            cluster-name: 
            cluster-nodes: localhost:9300
```

The default ElasticSearchConfiguration was:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(Client client, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client, new CustomEntityMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.createXmlMapper(false).build()));
    }            
}
```

Which I override with:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name}")
    private String clusterName;
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes}")
    private String clusterNodes;
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
            String server = clusterNodes.split(":")[0];
            Integer port = Integer.parseInt(clusterNodes.split(":")[1]);
            Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
            client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(server), port));
            return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client);
        }
    }
```

But I am still not able to connect elasticsearch using prod yml.

While debugging I got the following error while ElasticsearchTemplate bean creation:

**Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.toString()**

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: is there any solution for this? i am trying to connect to the remote. Please update with the answer

Comment: Did you ran the elastic search on remote? When using remote elasticsearch you can keep using the default ElasticSearchConfiguration. Just run elasticsearch on remote.

Comment: I am running my elasticsearch in aws instance and ports opened accordingly. unable to connect from another aws instance where my app is running. here is my issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5704#issuecomment-298911937. Need help this.

Comment: I have this issue today and when I downgrade ES from 2.4 to 1.7.3, the connection established

Comment: I'm confused, is your production cluster's master node running on localhost? The No nodes available message is trying to connect locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've a working Jhipster project with Elasticsearch. If your Elastic instance is running locally on default ports, you can leave those properties empty. It's not needed to change the class `ElasticSearchConfiguration`

> Using in Production
>
> In production, JHipster expects an external Elasticsearch instance. By
>   default, the application looks for an Elasticsearch instance running
>   on localhost. This can be configured by using the standard Spring Boot
>   properties, in the application-prod.yml file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more briefly?